# Android MediaPlayer: MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (10973, 0)

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

When i am playing 4-5 mp3 files, one after another, I get the following warning on logcat for every playback. What does it mean? and how to solve it?

> MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (10973, 0)

I checked [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java), but no luck

Thanks in advance